# Why is the PHP array not being appended?

Tags: php, arrays

This question is concerning the final state of variable `$message_to_user`

Consider the following simplified function:

```
function myArrayFunction()
{
    $message_to_user = array();

    $message_to_user[] = array('A Success Message', true);
    $message_to_user[] = array('An Error Message', false);

    echo $message_to_user;
    return $message_to_user;
}
```

**Notice** that I `echo` the array before returning it for troubleshooting and always get `Array` as the output.

**Question**

Why isn't the array getting appended with this syntax?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `echo` for displaying "complex" datastructures.

Comment: What's making you think that array keys do not appended?

Comment: According to your code: `$output = myArrayFunction(); echo $output[0][0]` will printout `A Success Message`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, you can't just `echo` an array like that. It will simply tell you "Hey bud, I'm an array."

Try using `var_dump($message_to_user)` or `print_r($message_to_user)`

Comment: I'm embarrassed I missed that. I'll set this answer as accepted because it is simple, concise, and more instructive (providing alternatives). Now am able to troubleshoot my script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo an array, use print_r();

```
function myArrayFunction()
{
    $message_to_user = array();

    $message_to_user[] = array('A Success Message', true);
    $message_to_user[] = array('An Error Message', false);

    print_r($message_to_user);
    return $message_to_user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php)  expects a string, as the documentation states.

> void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )

*Sidenote: echo is not a function anymore. Read the docs linked above.*

Arrays are not normal strings to be outputed. They are a collection of data and, for such objective, you need a proper function. PHP offers mainly the [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php) or the [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php), beeing the first one more human friendly and the secound able to show the data-type and length of each minimal part of the structure.

In PHP's documentation, you will offen find codes like this:

```
<pre>
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
</pre>
```

Just as another side note: that `<pre>` tag preserves the identation and line-breaking of the text, that is not considered by html when showing things. If you are as impatient as I am, you will also see such identation in the generated source-code as the browsers show them.

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.:** I'm not looking to overstep `RUJordan's` accepted answer or anyone else's.

Whether this will help and can prove to be helpful/useful, am only providing as an alternate answer and are welcome to use it.

The following will print:

0 => A Success Message
1 => An Error Message
2 => A Different Message
A Success Message
An Error Message
A Different Message

```
<?php
$myArray = array();
$myArray[0] = "A Success Message";
$myArray[1] = "An Error Message";
$myArray[2] = "A Different Message";

 foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
}

echo $myArray[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $myArray[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $myArray[2];
```

---

Whilst the following will produce the same result, minus the array keys:

A Success Message
An Error Message
A Different Message

```
<?php
$myArray = array();
$myArray[0] = "A Success Message";
$myArray[1] = "An Error Message";
$myArray[2] = "A Different Message";

foreach($myArray as $value){
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```